# How pass argument from form in view to coffee file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have view **messages/html.haml**

```
- if current_user
  .panel.panel-default#messages
    .panel-body
      %ul.media-list
        = render @messages, locals: { chanell: @chanell }

  .page-header
    %h1 Join the discussion!
  = render "form"
- else
  visit root_path
```

I need pass variable @chanel to client.subscribe methode in file **javascripts/messeges.coffee**

```
window.client = new Faye.Client('/faye')

jQuery ->
  $('#new_message').submit ->
    $(this).find("input[type='submit']").val('Sending...').prop('disabled', true)

  try
    client.unsubscribe "<%= params[:chanell] %>"
  catch
    console?.log "Can't unsubscribe."

  client.subscribe "<%= params[:chanell] %>", (payload) ->
    $('#messages').find('.media-list').append(payload.message) if payload.message
```

How it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic javascript with Ruby On Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506994/how-to-create-dynamic-javascript-with-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to set a data attribute with the value stored in channel.

So something like:

```js
jQuery ->
  $form = $('#new_message')
  channel = $form.data('channel')

  $form.submit ->
    $(this).find("input[type='submit']").val('Sending...').prop('disabled', true)

  try
    client.unsubscribe channel
  catch
    console?.log "Can't unsubscribe."

  client.subscribe channel, (payload) ->
    $('#messages').find('.media-list').append(payload.message) if payload.message
```

And then wherever you render your form, do something like the following:

```
form#new_message{data: { channel: @channel }}
```